# How to open a file in a Sharepoint site using VBA

Tags: vba, excel, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I am trying to open a file with a file name which changes every week. This means that the date part on the file name is varying. Also, this file is the ONLY file inside the folder. But its file name is changing. I am using the code below but it was throwing the error, 'Run time 52: Bad file name & number'. I need your help.

```
 Dim ThePath As String
 Dim TheFile As String

        ThePath = "https://ts.company.com/sites/folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4/"
        TheFile = Dir(ThePath & "MANILA_ShiftRecord_*" & ".xlsx")
        Workbooks.Open (ThePath & TheFile)
```

Thanks!

Comment: You can't use `Dir()` on a http path.  You may be able to use the WebDAV path, depending on how it's hosted.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1344910/get-the-content-of-a-sharepoint-folder-with-excel-vba

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24221462 This is VBA code that will parse WebDav URI's and allow VBA to open a file directly from SharePoint.

Answer (score 1):

If it's only one file you can use this approach:

```
Dim sharepointFolder As String
Dim colDisks As Variant
Dim objWMIService As Object
Dim objDisk As Variant
Dim driveLetter As String

'Create FSO and network object
Set objNet = CreateObject("WScript.Network")
Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

'Get all used Drive-Letters
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & "." & "\root\cimv2")
Set colDisks = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_LogicalDisk")

'Loop through used Drive-Letters
For Each objDisk In colDisks
    For i = 65 To 90
        'If letter is in use exit loop and remember letter.
        If i = Asc(objDisk.DeviceID) Then
            j = i
            Exit For
        'letters which are not checked yet are possible only
        ElseIf i > j Then
            driveLetter = Chr(i) & ":"
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
    'If a Drive-Letter is found exit the loop
    If driveLetter <> "" Then
        Exit For
    End If
Next

'define path to SharePoint
sharepointFolder = "https://spFolder/Sector Reports/"
'Map the sharePoint folder to the free Drive-Letter
objNet.MapNetworkDrive driveLetter, sharepointFolder
'set the folder to the mapped SharePoint-Path
Set folder = fs.GetFolder(driveLetter)
```

Afterwards you can handle the folder with filesystemobject functions.