# How to open an excel file from a Sharpoint

Tags: vba, excel, sharepoint

I'm trying to open an excel file from a sharepoint site using VBA. I used the code from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19505513/open-an-excel-file-from-sharepoint-site) page, but all it did was pull up my file explorer. I have also tried this code which I usually use for opening a closed workbook, not on a sharpoint.

```
dim wbk as workbook
set wbk = Workbooks.Open("Filepath")
```

Using this method returns an error telling me my file path is bad or non-existent, which my file path is correct. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: "Filepath" is not a valid path.

Comment: Use the full UNC Path to the file and it should open just fine

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim wbk as Workbook
Set wbk = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="\\filepath\file.xlsm", UpdateLinks:=False, ReadOnly:=True)
```

You need to include the syntax "filename". This iteration also opens the file as a read-only copy. To open as a file you can edit, remove the "ReadOnly:=True" portion of the code.