# VBA to open a particular excel file from an sharepoint folder

Tags: vba, excel

I want to open an Excel file which is stored in my SharePoint under the Folder

//Documents // Design //Excel //items.xlsx

I searched through Internet and came up with the below code. The Problem with the code is it is opening the "File open " Dialogue box in the local drive.

Can anyone, suggest me a code that I could work with and could open an Excel file from SharePoint

Here is what i tried, with the previous example tried in the Forum

```
Sub Share()
Dim S As Workbook
Dim WB As Variant

With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
.InitialFileName = "https://Sharepoint.de/Content/0030/default.aspx" & "/RootFolder=%2Fcontent%2F00008200%2FTeam%20Documents%2F02%20%2D%20Design%2F0001%20Design%2FExcel&FolderCTID=0x01200083BC38D90EC5674491B520CC48282737&View={28035ED9-59EF-42BE-BA4B-A36193C54539}&InitialTabId=Ribbon%2EDocument&VisibilityContext=WSSTabPersistence"

.AllowMultiSelect = False
.show

For Each WB In .SelectedItems
Set S = Workbooks.Open(WB)
Next
End With

If S Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

End Sub
```

Thanking you in advance

Comment: If you already know the filename, why are you showing the FileDialog?

Comment: @BensaysNotoPoliticsonSO then how do i proceed ?

Comment: @BensaysNotoPoliticsonSO sorry for the direct question, I am new to this platform

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Open an Excel file from SharePoint site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19505513/open-an-excel-file-from-sharepoint-site)

Comment: @BensaysNotoPoliticsonSO i tried the first solutin and it dint work

Comment: .... and what happened? What was the error message? etc...

Comment: @BensaysNotoPoliticsonSO it showed the file open Dialogue box from the local directory

Comment: @BensaysNotoPoliticsonSO it dint direct me to the path Name mentioned

Comment: Why are you trying to open the file dialog if you already know what file you want?

The file dialog is for you to *ask the user* what file to open. If you already know, you can skip that step and go straight to `Workbooks.Open`

Comment: @BensaysNotoPoliticsonSO ok, i will try like, i will give the path and give workbooks.open. I will try this and let you know, if i have any erros

Answer (score 1):

[This SO article](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19505513/7857211) covers your question quite well.
To access files within your filesystem (including network):

This method opens a certain workbook:

```
Workbooks.Open ("yourWorkbook.xls")
```

[Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Excel-VBA/articles/workbooks-open-method-excel) and [examples](http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/close-open.html) for this method.

If you actually want to open the folder, u can use this:

```
Application.FollowHyperlink "FolderLocation"
```

[Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/access-vba/articles/application-followhyperlink-method-access) for this method.

### Edit:

Use the UNC path as described in [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1344957/7857211) SO article. Add your file name to the path and access it with the methods from above.

You can substitute the `Cells(RowCtr, 1).Value = f.Name` from the sample code in the article with a simple `Debug.Print f.Name` to check the outcome.

Comment: thank you for suggesting. I followed the same  SO article and posted the above code.

Comment: Could you post an example how i could proceed. ?I am new to VBA and not able to exactly follow

Comment: Have you tried replacing `http://sharepoint...` with `\\sharepoint...` ?

Comment: Did you just alter the URL or use the UNC path?

Comment: I followed the first Option suggested in the post

Comment: the second was Little complex to understand, what they were doing

Comment: Updated my answer with a more in-depth explanation.

Comment: I will try it @david