# VBA to access Sharepoint with excel VBA FileSystemObject

Tags: excel, vba, ssl, sharepoint

I am trying to access a folder in Sharepoint that is secured (https). I am using a little VBA macro in excel that uses the file system object . see code below that was found in similar thread. the macro would open the .csv file in the folder and scan for a certain string.

Sometimes it would work but sometimes it would say 'path not found' in that case I would open the sharepoint site with Microsoft Explorer (browser) and then it all would have worked.
Now that explorer has been decommissioned I cannot open that path in explorer anymore .

any suggestion ? I know mapping/syncing the sharepoint would be another option but I want my tool to be used by different users and I guess mapping/syncing would make the new path , user dependent .

```vb
Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set oFolder = oFSO.GetFolder(//companyname.sharepoint.com@ssl/sites/Invoices/Shared Documents/Tre/daily)

For each oFile in oFolder.Files
 ...etc etc.
```

thanks
Marthomas

Comment: There's no easy way to work with SP folders/files in VBA.  MS has pretty much left its VBA users high and dry in this move over to SP.

Comment: [Some of this might be of use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19505513/open-an-excel-file-from-sharepoint-site)

Comment: thanks both for your replies , I found it shocking , but I guess MS is trying to steer towards Power Automate and such. I will try the various approaches proposed in the suggested link. like webdav . is just seems overly complicated for such a simple thing !

Comment: little update , I found in Microsoft Edge , under options ....'Reload page with internet explorer mode' . I opened the sharepoint site and the macro magically works !

Answer (score 0):

While IE is not available from User Interface, you still can use it in macro, so it is possible to login to SharePoint using IE and work with SharePoint.

Comment: Hi , thanks, I guess I can use the macro to open and close a IE session with the sharepoint . any chance you can share the VBA command line ?

Answer (score 0):

I tried some way to access sharepoint file via filesystemobject.
And find no way.
I think it is impossible to access sharepoint with filesystemobject.

I shall use other excel function to access my files. Other excel method may be valid for sharepoint files.

```
Sub SharePoint()
Dim strTestFolder As String, strTestBook As String, MyBook As Workbook

strTestFolder = "https://XXXXXXXX.sharepoint.com/sites/msteams_YYYYYYYY/Shared%20Documents/General/TEST/"
strTestBook = "NewBook.xlsx"

'This works well.
Set MyBook = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=strTestFolder & strTestBook)
MyBook.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1) = Date
MyBook.Sheets(1).Cells(2, 1) = Time
MyBook.Save
MyBook.Close
'My Excel can open workbooks in sharepoint folder

Dim FSO As Object, objMyFolder As Object, objFile As Object
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

'Check my workbook with FSO
If FSO.FileExists(strTestFolder & strTestBook) Then 'Same name as Workbooks.Open
    MsgBox "File Exists"
Else
    MsgBox strTestFolder & strTestBook & " does not Exists" 'Excel shows this message. FSO can not recognize my workbook.
End If


'Convert path Patern1
strTestFolder = "//XXXXXXXX.sharepoint.com/sites/msteams_YYYYYYYY/Shared%20Documents/General/TEST/"
If FSO.FileExists(strTestFolder & strTestBook) Then
    MsgBox "File Exists"
Else
    MsgBox strTestFolder & strTestBook & " does not Exists" 'Excel shows this message. FSO can not recognize my workbook.
End If

'Convert path Patern2
strTestFolder = "\\XXXXXXXX.sharepoint.com\sites\msteams_YYYYYYYY\Shared%20Documents\General\TEST\"
If FSO.FileExists(strTestFolder & strTestBook) Then
    MsgBox "File Exists"
Else
    MsgBox strTestFolder & strTestBook & " does not Exists" 'Excel shows this message. FSO can not recognize my workbook.
End If

'Convert path Patern3
strTestFolder = "https://XXXXXXXX.sharepoint.com/sites/msteams_YYYYYYYY/Shared Documents/General/TEST/"
If FSO.FileExists(strTestFolder & strTestBook) Then 'Same name as Workbooks.Open
    MsgBox "File Exists"
Else
    MsgBox strTestFolder & strTestBook & " does not Exists" 'Excel shows this message. FSO can not recognize my workbook.
End If

'Convert path Patern4
strTestFolder = "//XXXXXXXX.sharepoint.com/sites/msteams_YYYYYYYY/Shared Documents/General/TEST/"
If FSO.FileExists(strTestFolder & strTestBook) Then
    MsgBox "File Exists"
Else
    MsgBox strTestFolder & strTestBook & " does not Exists" 'Excel shows this message. FSO can not recognize my workbook.
End If

'Convert path Patern5
strTestFolder = "\\XXXXXXXX.sharepoint.com\sites\msteams_YYYYYYYY\Shared Documents\General\TEST\"
If FSO.FileExists(strTestFolder & strTestBook) Then
    MsgBox "File Exists"
Else
    MsgBox strTestFolder & strTestBook & " does not Exists" 'Excel shows this message. FSO can not recognize my workbook.
End If
```

End Sub