# CreateTextFile method of "Scripting.FileSystemObject" object failing

Tags: excel, vba

In my Excel VBA I have the following:

```
Dim newFile As String
Dim fso As Object
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set newFile = fso.CreateTextFile(currPath & "\" & txtFileName)
```

when currPath is a valid file address (e.g.:  C:\temp   ) then the CreateTextFile method is successful.

BUT ...

when currPath is pointing to a SharePoint Folder (in my company's "cloud") (e.g.: "https://mycompany.sharepoint.com/somefolder/anotherfolder/anotherfolder"  the CreateTextFile method fails.

Because this is a URL and the CreateTextFile needs a fileaddress I changed the URL to a fileaddress as follows:

```
If InStr(currPath,".sharepoint.") > 0 then
currPathLength = Len(currPath)
currPath = Right(currPath, (currPathLength-8))
currPath="\\" & Replace(currPath, "/", "\")
End If
```

Resulting in the following currPath value:
"\mycompany.sharepoint.com\somefolder\anotherfolder\anotherfolder"

This was not the total correction that was needed.  It still failed with

"Error in MyFunction(): -2147417848 - Method 'CreateTextFile' of object 'IFileSystem3' failed"

Do you have any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: Same problem/question as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73114050/vba-to-access-sharepoint-with-excel-vba-filesystemobject?

Comment: I use OneDrive to sync SharePoint Folders. Then I can just use the local drive and folder structure to do whatever I want and OneDrive will do the rest. Or you try to go this [path](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24221462/6600940)

Comment: Another option would be to map the sharepoint folder to a network drive but then you might need to provide credentials as well.