# VBA run-time error 76 - Path not found in excel not working suddenly

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error

I'm having a problem with my macro to move some files around.
It worked for me a couple of weeks ago and now it gives me a run-time error.

```
Sub test()
Dim fso As Object
Dim SourceFileName As String, DestinFileName As String, oldname As String, newname As String

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.Filesystemobject")
SourceFileName = ThisWorkbook.path & "/Test1**"
' oldplace = Replace(SourceFileName, "/", "\")
DestinFileName = ThisWorkbook.path & "/resultat/"
' newplace = Replace(DestinFileName, "/", "\")

fso.MoveFile Source:=SourceFileName, Destination:=DestinFileName

MsgBox (SourceFileName + " Moved to " + DestinFileName)
End Sub
```

As is seen from the code, I have tried to change "/" to "\", but it made no difference.
I have tried to create new folders and files to move around, with no luck.

I do not have the option to create a shorter path as I'm on a sharepoint and the path I can change is only 5 characters long.

I feel like i have look at all the questions here and googled it without luck.

Comment: Was it on sharepoint when it worked ?

Comment: Have you seen this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19505513/open-an-excel-file-from-sharepoint-site

Comment: Yes it has always been on sharepoint.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, however I don't know WHY this works.

But putting onedrive automatic sync on pause helped.
This gave me a local path insted of a sharepoint.