# Find by keyword from another worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

How I can fix it?
I would like to find cells by using keyword in another sheets in specific cell

```
Sub macro()
 
  Workbooks.Open "Link of workbook2", ReadOnly:=True
 
Dim updateddate As String
Dim updatedmonth As String
 
updateddate = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Update logsheet").Range("B11").Value
updatedmonth = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Update logsheet").Range("B12").Value
 
Workbooks("nameofworkbook2").Activate
 
Sheets("updatedmonth").Select
Set cell = Range("A4:V4").Find("updateddate")
 
End Sub
```

Comment: Are `nameofworkbook2`  and `Link of workbook2` the same workbook? What's the next step after `Find`?

Comment: It’s same workbook. But thisworkbook is  another workbook. Next step after find I will go down 2 rows. Then select all cells with data and copy.

Answer (score 0):

- Qualify all cell references (Range, Cells, Rows ..) with sheet object
- Opening workbook with full file path ( path + file name ) is more reliable
- Use object variables (oWK, oSht..) to simplify the code
- You don't need select/active in most case

[How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba/10717999#10717999)

```vb
Sub macro()
    Dim sPath As String, sWKName As String, oWK As Workbook
    sPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\"
    sWKName = "nameofworkbook2.xlsx"
    Set oWK = Workbooks.Open(sPath & sWKName, ReadOnly:=True)
    Dim updateddate As String, updatedmonth As String
    Dim oCell As Range, vMatch, oSht As Worksheet
    Set oSht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Update logsheet")
    updateddate = oSht.Range("B11").Value
    updatedmonth = oSht.Range("B12").Value
    With oWK.Sheets(updatedmonth)
        vMatch = Application.Match(CLng(CDate(updateddate)), .Rows(4), 0)
        If IsError(vMatch) Then
            MsgBox "Can't find " & updateddate
        Else
            Set oCell = .Cells(4, vMatch)
            ' You code
        End If
    End With
    oWK.Close False
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your help but workbook can’t be opened due to it’s in shared point. Could you please help to edit?

Comment: Try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19505513/open-an-excel-file-from-sharepoint-site